Nginx force www and HTTPS on subdomains
Let's imagine I have the following domains: example.ie / example.co.uk. I want to force with nginx that all requests are prefixed with www and using HTTPS.
I have the following:
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.ie;

        # SSL related settings.
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ie/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ie/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.example.ie;

        # Proxy related configuration.
        ........

        # SSL related settings.
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ie/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ie/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.co.uk;

        # SSL related settings.
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co.uk/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co.uk/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.example.co.uk;

        # Proxy related configuration.
        ........

        # SSL related settings.
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co.uk/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co.uk/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

This configuration works but when running nginx -t I'm getting
protocol options redefined for 0.0.0.0:443

It might sound obvious but I'm using completely different server names between the configurations but they somehow are overlapping. What am I missing here?

Cross-site dupe: https://serverfault.com/q/1131318

I was indeed lacking the http2 directive on all server blocks. Want to add that as an answer so I can accept it?
